# Transparent material looks different in render/camera than in preview in Eevee

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I've seen a few different questions with similar problems on here but none of the solutions appear to work for/apply to my issue. [This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126530/final-render-looks-different-than-preview-render) seems closest to the problem I'm having, but I don't have a volume so I don't think that's what's happening here. I've downloaded an eyeball mesh (from turbosquid, I think? It was a hot second ago) and I've used it in Cycles before with no trouble, but I decided to see how it would look in Eevee, and it looks fine in rendered preview mode:
[image]

It looks like that in Cycles, too, which is what I want. But then I go into the camera view, and it looks like this:
[image]

Here are the nodes for the transparent material of the eyeballs:
[image]

Is it the shading language? I read in the linked post above that the camera and render take more calculations into account than just the preview. I'm just not sure if that's the problem here or not.
Thanks in advance for any insight. I've only used Eevee a few times in the past so I'm not super familiar with it, sorry.

Comment: Could you explain very directly exactly what the difference is that you are wanting explained between the two render images? Because you have explained everything but the exact character of the display difference itself, thereby leaving it to everyone else to discover the problem from nothing more than a difference in how these two images appear visually on their own screens. This will leave many wondering if they are seeing the same thing that you are seeing. Personally, I can't be sure I see it. Even if I could, I couldn't be sure it's the same difference you are seeing. Could you tell us?

Comment: @R-800 The difference is that in the first image, which is a screenshot of the render preview mode, the eyes appear bright blue which is what I want. The second image, which is a screenshot of how the eyes appear from the camera view and in the final render, and they look very dark and dull. I want the eyes to look like the first image in the final render, but I think I have some setting enabled where the camera and the render are calculating different shadings in the material than in the preview. I have not changed anything between the two images, just switched to camera view. Does that help?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66702/objects-behind-glass-shader-appear-black?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/objects-behind-glass-appear-too-dark